# Does Mailgun validate new email addresses before sending a message in the same way their 'Email Validation' service validates an email?

Tags: mailgun

I'm confused as to whether sending an email with Mailgun.com by default validates new email addresses, or if I should choose to use the 'Email Validation' service before attempting to send an email to a new email address.

In addition if validation is handled by default with new email addresses does this increase the cost - in terms of the 'validation' pricing?

Comment: I understand reputation can be hurt when sending to bad email addresses, but I assume reputation wouldn't be affected if Mailgun by default validates a new email address before actually sending it. Or is reputation hurt only within the Mailgun service? - that is if we don't use the 'Email Validation' service?